# delete physical file after deleting the record of a table in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

what i want is to delete the image file  after deleting the record of a table in database

my database consisting 4 tables, linking with primary keys and foreign keys.

the 4 tables are : Brand, Product, Content, Promotion.  All consisting column "brandID" and having a column of "file path"

tables are altered to "ON DELETE CASCADE"  so the records of others table will be deleted  when a "brandID" is deleted.

** i save image file to server, file path to database. Again, what i want is to delete the physical file in server  when i delete the file path(entry) of a table..

any advise is highly appreciated.

im new to DB, below is the links i red.. i need more information..

thanks again

[Can we delete the physical file from server when I delete the corresponding entry from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907636/can-we-delete-the-physical-file-from-server-when-i-delete-the-corresponding-entr)

[How to delete files when a record is deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600834/how-to-delete-files-when-a-record-is-deleted)

[delete file using MySQL procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527514/delete-file-using-mysql-procedure)

Comment: The php function to delete files is "unlink(string $path)", just give your path to it and it shoudl work if you set the permissions correctly.

Comment: he asking for ON DELETE CASCADE deletion of physical files on server as well

Comment: Are you really using Microsoft SQL Server (you've tagged it, but in the body of your post mention MySQL)?

Comment: i just want to get advises from all of you and i thought they are quite similar in term of concept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL can't really perform such filesystem actions for you automatically*.  Instead, your application code that issues the `DELETE` statement to the server should invoke a filesystem operation to remove the file.

Therefore you will need to:

1. Select the filepath from the database;
2. Delete the records from the database (cascading foreign key constraints can ensure that all associated records are deleted as appropriate); and
3. Delete the file from the filesystem.  One presumes that your application is in PHP (since your question is so tagged), in which case you can call [`unlink()`](http://php.net/unlink) to delete the file.

---

<sup>* This is not entirely correct, as one could use a UDF to delete the file from a trigger, but this will generally open a number of security vulnerabilities which are rarely worth the tradeoff.</sup>

Comment: what im trying to do now is looping all the table to match and unlink. will update if i manage to make it

Answer (score 0):

this is what i've done. If you notice, the deleting file and deleting database records are separated because the database tables are connecting by reference key, thus the deleting records part is quite easy by using "ON DELETE CASCADE" .

**the database was designed to only store the path of the uploaded file

To delete the file, firstly, i create a query to obtain all the file location with a title "pictureLocation" , then unlink them 1 by 1 in the loop as shown as below

```
<?php

.....

.....

    //query and make file path  AS 'pictureLocation'


    if($table == "something_user"){
    $query= sprintf ("SELECT userID,userLogo AS 'pictureLocation' 
        FROM something_user
        WHERE $idTitle=$id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT userID,contentImage 
        FROM something_content
        WHERE $idTitle=$id  
        UNION ALL
        SELECT userID,promoImg 
        FROM something_promo
        WHERE $idTitle=$id 
        ORDER BY userID"  );

        }
        else if($table == "something_product"){
                $query= sprintf ("SELECT productID, contentImage AS 'pictureLocation'
                FROM something_content
                WHERE $idTitle=$id
                UNION ALL
                SELECT productID, promoImg
                FROM something_promo
                WHERE $idTitle=$id
                ORDER BY productID" );
                }
                else if ...


        else{
            //do nothing
        }


$result = mysql_query($query);      //execute the query , put into $result

$numrow = mysql_num_rows($result);  //for error checking
$removeCount = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {    //fetch array to $row

$deletepath = "../".$row['pictureLocation'];        //adding  ../  to the path 
                                            //*pictureLocation storing the file path retrieved from query

    if(file_exists($deletepath)){
        echo "exist".$deletepath;

        if(unlink($deletepath)){
        $deletecount++;
        }
        else{ 
            die("unlink error");
            }

    }
    else{       //if file not exist
        echo $deletepath."not here";
        $deletecount++;
    }


}
//end of file deletion


    //if delete count equal to number of query, delete database entry
    if($removeCount == $numrow){

    $updateSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM ".$_GET["table_name"]." WHERE $idTitle = %s",
                GetSQLValueString($id, "text"));        //defend against injection
    }

    mysql_query($updateSQL, $DBConnect) or die(mysql_error());
} 
else{
    $error = 1;
}
mysql_close();
```

any advises or improvements for the code is very appreciated. 
Thanks!